# What does the switch statement in this RxJS example do?

Tags: switch-statement, rxjs5

I don't understand what the following documentation means in this [RxJS example](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switch). Can someone answer?

> The outcome is that `switched` is essentially a timer that restarts
>   on every click. The interval Observables from older clicks do not
>   merge with the current interval Observable.

Here is the code:

```
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
// Each click event is mapped to an Observable that ticks every second
var higherOrder = clicks.map((ev) => Rx.Observable.interval(1000));
var switched = higherOrder.switch();
// The outcome is that `switched` is essentially a timer that restarts
// on every click. The interval Observables from older clicks do not merge
// with the current interval Observable.
switched.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest model to understand for switch is `autocomplete`.

In the typical autocomplete scenario you will take input from a user, and call a service that returns a promise.   You then attach to the promise through `.then()` to update your UI.

```
function onChange(text: string) {
    this.request(url).then((data) => this.updateListBox(data))
}
```

If the user enters text multiple times you'll call `onChange` each time.  The order of responses at that point is not guarnteed. The endpoint you're calling could very well return you responses out of order.  `1`, `3`, `2`.  So the user will see the second request they made, instead of the last request they made.

Now what switch does, is given an input observable, it only actively listens to the last observable emitted to it. For example...

```
this.onChange
   .map(text => Observable.fromPromise(this.request(text))
   .switch()
   .subscribe((data) => this.updateListBox(data));
```

Each time a value comes in through `onChange` we will still make the request as per normal.  Once a second value emits from `onChange` we `unsubscribe` from the first observable (request 1).  And subscribe to the second observable (request 2).

So that once you update the UI, you only ever update with the latest set of data that you care about.

Comment: Your example well describes it, but an answer for the example in the question is appreciated.

Comment: With that example in the question it's simply, every time the `document` is clicked a new timer is created (starting from `0`).  The old one is disposed of automatically as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing a real use case for switch(). This is much more understandable for me than the example from the official documentation, which uses nested range() functions.